# Map $\mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n$ homotopic to identity

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $F: \mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n$ be a continuous map such that $F(x)\ne -x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{S}^n$. Prove that $F$ is homotopic to the identity map $\mathbb{S}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the homotopy:
$$
 \Phi(t,x) = \frac{(1-t)F(x)+tx}{\lvert (1-t)F(x)+tx\rvert}
$$
the condition $F(x)+x\neq 0$ guarantees that the denumerator is always positive.

Comment: Geometrically, if $x,y$ are two distinct points on $S^n$ with $x\neq -y$ there is a unique "great circle" that contains $x,y$, and the homotopy follows that shortest path on the great circle from $F(x)$ to $x$. (When $F(x)=x$ the homotopy is constant on $x$.)